# failed to connect Amazon RDS using MySQL workbench

Tags: mysql, ssl, mysql-workbench, rds

I can connect RDS on my school's computer using MySQL workbench several months ago.
Now, when I tried again at home, it always said:

[image]

I don't remember how did I managed to connect RDS on my school's computer.

I use default security group (I am not sure if I added my ip address in the right place) and I have added my ip address to inbound rules:

[image]

But it still said the same thing.

What's wrong with it?

Comment: What is your problem actually? The dialog says the connection is fine.

Comment: Thanks for asking, it is really a stupid mistake. I thought this windows means a warning so I download the SSL CA. But it seems that I just missed the "OK" button.